# Related rates - approximation or not?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, approximation

> The radius of a uniform spherical balloon is increasing at 3% per
>   second. Find the % rate at which its volume is increasing.

My solution:
Percentage is change of some value divided by that value so the percentage rate at which the volume is increasing will be given by:
$$\frac{\frac{dv}{V}}{dt}$$

We already know that $$\frac{\frac{dr}{r}}{dt}=3\frac{\%}{s}$$
Then:
$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = \frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{\frac{dr}{r}}* \frac{\frac{dr}{r}}{dt}$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = \frac{dV}{V}* \frac{r}{dr} * 3$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = \frac{dV}{dr}* \frac{r}{V} * 3$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = 4\pi r^{2}* \frac{r}{V} * 3$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = \frac{4\pi r^{3}}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3}} * 3$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = \frac{4\pi r^{3}}{\frac{4}{3}\pi r^{3}} * 3$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = 3 * 3$$

$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{dt} = 9\frac{\%}{s}$$

Questions:

1) Is such reasoning correct? I'm particularly concerned about this transformation:
$$\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{\frac{dr}{r}}=\frac{dV}{dr}* \frac{r}{V}$$

I remember reading that I can't treat derivatives as fractions but it happens to work here and this confuses me.

2) Is the final result exactly 9 % per second or is this only an approximation? For example the answer to:

> If $V=2x^{3}$ what is the approximate percentage change in $V$ when
>   $x$ changes by 2%?

is 6% but this is only an approximation (see [Is dv only approximate of dv/dx*dx?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452169/is-dv-only-approximate-of-dv-dxdx#1452185)) Is this the case in the original exercise or is 9 % per second an exact result?

Answer (score 1):

The actual percentage increase of the volume is $100\cdot(1.03^3-1)\% = 9.2727\%$, so your result of $9\%$ is only an approximation.

You could rephrase your problem just like the one at the bottom of your post:

> If $V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$ and $r$ increases by $3\%$, what is the $\%$ increase in $V$?

Well if

$$
V_\text{old} = \frac{4}{3} \pi r_\text{old}^3
$$

and $r_\text{new} = 1.03r_\text{old}$, then

$$
\begin{align}
V_\text{new} &= \frac{4}{3}\pi r_\text{new}^3 \\
    &= \frac{4}{3} \pi r_\text{old}^3 \cdot 1.03^3 \\
    &= 1.03^3 V_\text{old}.
\end{align}
$$

So, $V$ increased by a factor of $1.03^3$, and hence its percentage increase is $100\cdot(1.03^3-1)\%$.

---

The reason your method gives the wrong answer is that

$$
\frac{\frac{dr}{r}}{dt}=3\frac{\%}{s}
$$

should actually be

$$
\frac{\frac{dr}{r}}{dt}=\log(1.03).
$$

Note that $\log(1.03) \approx 0.03 = 3\%$ because $\log(1+x) \approx x$ for small $x$.  This is why your answer is approximately correct.

If the percentage increase in $r$ was much larger than $3\%$, say $50\%$, your approximation would be much worse: your method would say that $V$ would increase by $150\%$, while the actual percentage increase would be $237.5\%$.

Why the logarithm? Well, you know that $r$ is increasing proportionally to its size, i.e.

$$
\frac{dr}{dt} = cr
$$

for some constant $c$.  We can solve this equation and get

$$
r(t) = r_0 e^{ct}.
$$

To find out what $c$ should be we use the assumption that $r$ increases by $3\%$.  After $1$ second, $r$ should be equal to $3\%$ more than $r_0$, and this is $1.03r_0$. Plugging this in,

$$
\begin{align}
r(1) &= r_0 e^c \\
1.03 r_0 &= r_0 e^c,
\end{align}
$$

and cancelling $r_0$ from both sides gives

$$
1.03 = e^c,
$$

so $c = \log(1.03)$.  Thus

$$
\frac{dr/dt}{r} = \log(1.03).
$$

This should be your starting point.

---

Now, the reason everything you write after this works (i.e. why treating differentials like fractions works here) is that there are hidden "$/dt$"s floating around underneath everything that you have simply neglected to write. So, while your method is essentially correct, the way you have written it is not. The equation

$$
\frac{\frac{dV}{V}}{\frac{dr}{r}}=\frac{dV}{dr}* \frac{r}{V},
$$

for instance, makes no sense. Here's how your calculation should be written:

$$
\frac{dr}{dt} = r\log(1.03), \tag{1}
$$

so

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac{dV}{dr} \frac{dr}{dt} \qquad \text{(chain rule)} \\
&= 4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt} \\
&= 4\pi r^3 \log(1.03) \\
&= V 3\log(1.03). \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$

Now there are two ways we can get back to the percentage increase. The first is to notice that we got the coefficient $\log(1.03)$ in equation $(1)$ by taking the log of $103\%$, so if we want a percentage from $3\log(1.03)$ then we should do the opposite and exponentiate it, giving

$$
e^{3\log(1.03)}\% = 1.03^3\% = 109.2727\%, \tag{3}
$$

which represents an increase of $9.2727\%$.

The second way we could obtain this answer is by solving the differential equation $(2)$ for $V$, obtaining

$$
V(t) = V_0 e^{3\log(1.03)t} = V_0 (1.03)^{3t}.
$$

The initial size of $V$ is $V(0) = V_0$, and after $1$ second its size is

$$
V(1) = V_0 1.03^3,
$$

so it has increased by a factor of $1.03^3 = 1.092727$, which is an increase of

$$
100\cdot(1.03^3 - 1)\% = 9.2727\%.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped. But I still need some intuitive way to understand the equation dr/dt=cr (where c is a constant). Now I understand why it should be a logarithm but at the same time I can't find any argument for why it shouldn't be 0.03r, for example, it seems to fit. I mean, there must be some factor we forget to take into account when we do the approximation of 0.03r instead of the logarithm but I can't locate the source of that discrepancy, could you give me some insight so I can intuitively understand why there should be a logarithm? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to answer that in the section that begins "Why the logarithm?" Is there a specific part of that explanation that isn't clear?

Comment: @Richard, try this one: Let $r_k$ be the value of $r$ after $k$ seconds. We know that $$\frac{dr_k}{dt} = cr_k$$ for some $c$. By definition $$\frac{dr_k}{dt} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{r(k+h) - r(k)}{h} \approx \frac{r(k+1)-r(k)}{1} = r_{k+1} - r_k,$$ and substituting this into the previous equation yields $$r_{k+1} - r_k \approx cr_k$$ and, adding $r_k$ to both sides, $$r_{k+1} \approx (1+c)r_k.$$ Based on this we would guess that $c \approx 0.03$ in order to satisfy the requirement that $r_k$ increases by $3\%$ as $k$ increases to $k+1$...

Comment: ...But since this is only an approximation, there is no reason to believe this is exactly the right value for $c$. In essence, taking $c=0.03$ is an error pretty much because it assumes $\frac{dr}{dt} = r(t+1) - r(t)$, which is not true.